# Generalizing the Uncertainty Principle for acceleration, jerk, etc

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, observables

The [Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) states that the more you know about a particles position, the less you know about its velocity and vice-versa, and there is an equality $\sigma_x\sigma_p \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$ which states this in a more precise way.  I was wondering if this inequality could be altered and generalized to relate different derivatives of position, such as position and acceleration, velocity and acceleration, velocity and jerk, or really any two (or possibly even more than two) derivatives of position.  I do not have a physics background.

Comment: What would be a time derivative of the position in quantum mechanics?

Comment: As I said, I do not have a physics background.  I had assumed it would have been velocity, but based on your question, I'm assuming that the time derivative of position doesn't make much sense in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) is one that has been successful to describe  observations at the particle level, but can now be derived from the basic theory of quantum mechanics.  ([here is the history](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200802/physicshistory.cfm) of how it was developed by Heisenberg) The one you quote is about position and momentum being constrained when measured together. It depends on the mathematics of quantum mechanics.

There are more possible uncertainty relations, but they are derived from the mathematical theory, so not arbitrary generalizations , as you suggest.

Comment: Your last sentence confuses me.  Deriving new uncertainty relations from the existing mathematical theory is along the lines of what I was suggesting, but perhaps not stated clearly.

Comment: they are different variables, for example energyand time, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html . Your question seems to imply the delta(x) to be one of the variablse

Comment: Ahhh.  Thank you for your original answer and your clarification.

Comment: So I'm guessing my main mistake is assuming the uncertainty principle deals with velocity when in fact it deals with momentum, but I'm not sure.

Comment: uncertainties come with coupling two variables, but yes it deals with momentum and space. As the other answer says, you can try to use the dxdp HUP to try and see if there are quantum mechanical operators that would give what you are explicitly asking, based on the dpdx basic uncertainty. Mathematics is powerful.

Comment: @annav that HUP has been imposed by observations at the particle level sounds a little too strong statement. I would rather say that historically it was a way to *interpret* theoretical results in agreement with experiments.

Comment: @GiorgioP  You are correct, I have edited, thanks.

Comment: @annav based on your comment about delta(x) not being one of the variables, I was wondering if mass in quantum mechanics is "messier" than it is in Newtonian mechanics?  Originally I was treating mass as a constant and so it could be ignored as a variable, leaving only velocity as a variable rather than momentum.

Comment: @NullSimplex mass in special relativity is used for particle physics, and yes it is "messier" . It  is the "length" of the energy momentum four vector.See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: @annav I see.  I recall hearing in relativity that as objects approach the speed of light, there mass grows indefinitely, so a fast moving particle's momentum would get more complicated I suppose.

Comment: The mass in approaching the speed of light follows the same algebra but it is the **inertial** mass, not the invariant mass of the object, that is, the mass that fulfills the classical f=ma, how much force should be exerted to get acceleration. It is not used for particle physics.

Answer (score 4):

As Anna is saying, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is a fundamental property of nature. It is not that this relation was defined using mathematical concepts *only*, but was derived *rigorously* using results and *postulates* of quantum mechanics such as the [Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson.E2.80.93Schr.C3.B6dinger_uncertainty_relations) $$\sigma_A^2 \sigma_B^2 \geq \left(\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\langle[\hat{A},\hat{B} ]\rangle \right)^2 $$

and the commutator relation $$[\hat{x},\hat{p}] = i\hbar$$ the concept that a quantum state can be expressed as the linear combination $$| \psi \rangle = \sum_n c_n |n\rangle$$ and the expectation value of quantities, for example energy $$
\langle E\rangle = \langle \psi | H | \psi \rangle$$

along with other quantum mechanical concepts and postulates. ***If*** you could determine the uncertainty relations you want, these would be mathematical relations with no physical meaning.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to "generalize" the Uncertainty Relations (UR), in the sense that it is possible to obtain other UR's, from the algebra of position and momentum, although only for observables that depend on them.

The starting point is the [generalized form of the UR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), valid for the two generic symmetric operators $A$ and $B$:
$$
\sigma_A \sigma_B \geq \left| \frac{1}{2i} \langle[A,B] \rangle  \right|,
$$
where $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$  are the standard deviations of the distributions of the values of the two observables in a given quantum state, and $\langle[A,B] \rangle $ is the expectation value of the commutator $AB-BA$ in the same state.

Therefore, all we need is the commutator of $A$ and $B$. This can be easily obtained from the basic commutator of positions and momenta $[x_i,p_j]=i\hbar \delta_{ij}$ for any observable which could be written as an analytical function of them (one has to use some basic [commutator identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)).

Notice that to obtain the quantum UR for classical quantities, one has to provide a reasonable expression of these quantities as operators in terms of position and momentum. For example, a velocity operator can be naturally defined as ${\bf p}/m$. For higher-order derivatives, the problem is to find a reasonable definition in terms of position and momentum.